# Login prompt not shown for Windows Authentication

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I have viewed numerous StackOverflow, and SerFault, questions which touch on this very problem. However, none of those answers have helped me out. Here's my situation.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 website which has an Area configured. That Area has Anon Authentication and Windows Authentication enabled. The site root only has Anon Authorization enabled. There are no web.config changes which control the authorization of the Area - we simply wanted to control security from IIS.

When I navigate to a url in the Area, instead of being prompted with a login prompt, I am shown a 401.0 error page.

> HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page.

The login prompt did appear before, both on my PC and the test server, but now both websites are no longer displaying the login prompt. I did apply some VS2010 updates to my PC the other day, so I thought that was at fault, but the test server is still the same config - nothing has changed, so I ruled out the updates as being at fault.

I generated an IIS log where most of it wasn't very helpful. The only interesting part was this warning:

> > -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
> >
> > ModuleName ManagedPipelineHandler   Notification 128 HttpStatus 401
> >     HttpReason Unauthorized   HttpSubStatus 0    ErrorCode 0
> >     ConfigExceptionInfo
> >
> > Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
> >
> > ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)

I've tried Chrome, IE and FireFox and neither of them display the login prompt, so it's not an issue isolated to a specific browser.

I'm really stuck here, any help would be appreciated.